# Ceiling fan remote not working

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan, fans

I lost the canopy bracket along with the receiver and remote to my ceiling fan while moving. I then ordered an exact replacement receiver and remote for the fan, and when I had someone install it, the remote still didn't work for some reason. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: If the installer could not figure it out, then he should have called the manufacturer... and/or told you something about the problem. We really need more information to be helpful to you. Otherwise, did you make sure the batteries are in the correct orientation (+/-)? Do you have a manual? What's the make and model? Can you add a picture?

Comment: Did you follow the manufacturer's installation instructions to pair the remote and receiver (if required)?

Comment: It is a fan from Lamps Plus called a Casa Vieja Compass fan. Here is the link. http://www.lampsplus.com/products/52-inch-casa-compass-brushed-nickel-ceiling-fan__m2565.html.

I do not have the manual anymore and had someone install it before I moved.

Answer (score 1):

you probably have the dip switches set differently in the transmitter compared to the receiver.  you just need to open the receiver housing, check the switches and make sure they are set the same in the transmitter (assuming same model, frequency, etc is correct)